# How to copy a two-dimensional array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

This method works fine.  However, I think it is not functional.

```
fun getCopy(array: Array<BooleanArray>): Array<BooleanArray> {
    val copy = Array(array.size) { BooleanArray(array[0].size) { false } }
    for (i in array.indices) {
        for (j in array[i].indices) {
            copy[i][j] = array[i][j]
        }
    }
    return copy
}
```

Is there a more functional way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make use of [`clone`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-cloneable/) like so:

```
fun Array<BooleanArray>.copy() = map { it.clone() }.toTypedArray()
```

or if you'd like to save some allocations:

```
fun Array<BooleanArray>.copy() = arrayOfNulls<ByteArray>(size).let { copy ->
    forEachIndexed { i, bytes -> copy[i] = bytes.clone() }
    copy
} as Array<BooleanArray>
```

or even more concise as suggested by [@hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196460/hotkey):

```
fun Array<BooleanArray>.copy() = Array(size) { get(it).clone() }
```

Comment: Another allocation-efficient implementation: `fun Array<BooleanArray>.copy() = Array(size) { get(it).clone() }`

Answer (score -1):

What about using `copyOf()`?

```
val copyOfArray = array.copyOf()
```

> Returns new array which is a copy of the original array

Reference [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/copy-of.html)

Comment: the sample code in the question indicates that a deep copy is required. this code creates a shallow copy.

Comment: This keeps references of internal array