# Copy 2d array to separate variable in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, kotlin

So i have this 2d array, and i want to copy it to another *seperate* variable. I have tried using `System.arrayCopy` and `Array.copyOf`, but both seem to just return a reference to the array i'm trying to copy, not a new array. Are there any buildt in methods for this, or do i have to make one myself?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin, like Java, doesn't really have multi-dimensional arrays.  What it does have is arrays of arrays.  So what you have is an array, each element of which is another array.  It looks like a 2-dimensional array most of the time, but you've found a case where it doesn't!

What functions like `System.arrayCopy` do is create a copy of the outer array; but it's a *shallow copy*, which still refers to the same inner arrays as the original.

What you want is a *deep copy*, which creates copies of all the inner arrays too.

See [How to copy a two-dimensional array in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463390/how-to-copy-a-two-dimensional-array-in-kotlin) or [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java) for a few examples of that.