# How to clone or copy a 2d list in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, arraylist, copy

following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46846025/10148104)

below provided for the test case

```
@Test
fun testKotlinArrayCopy() {

    data class Person(val name: String, var friends: List<Person>, var isHungry: Boolean = false)

    val okyFriends = listOf(
        Person(name = "Billy", friends = listOf()),
    )

    val peopleAtBlock1 : ArrayList<Person> = arrayListOf(
        Person(name = "Oky", friends = okyFriends),
    )

    val peopleAtBlock2 : ArrayList<Person>  = ArrayList(peopleAtBlock1.toMutableList())


    peopleAtBlock1[0].friends[0].isHungry = true
    
    // here i expect variable peopleAtBlock2 doesn't changed 
    // because i just change the peopleAtBlock1 only
    assertFalse(peopleAtBlock1[0] == peopleAtBlock2[0])
    
}
```

when i run the test it fails because the `peopleAtBlock2` changed unexpectedly caused by this code

```
peopleAtBlock1[0].friends[0].isHungry = true
```

i want to keep value of `peopleAtBlock2` is not changed, how do i do that?

thanks

**EDIT**:

i have follow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463390/how-to-copy-a-two-dimensional-array-in-kotlin) using

```
fun Array<BooleanArray>.copy() = map { it.clone() }.toTypedArray()
```

converted to my case, the function would be

```
fun ArrayList<Person>.copy2() = map { it.copy() }.toTypedArray()
```

but still doesn't work

please check [my repl](https://replit.com/@AhmadNashihuddi/list2dDataClass#main.kt) for running in cloud if you dont have kotlin

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463390/how-to-copy-a-two-dimensional-array-in-kotlin

Comment: i see, thanks, wait

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463390/how-to-copy-a-two-dimensional-array-in-kotlin
Don't have enough rep to comment yet sorry

Comment: hold on let me try the code

Comment: @ShobhitTewari it doesn't work, please check my edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `peopleAtBlock2` is a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/in-java-what-is-a-shallow-copy) of `peopleAtBlock1`, which means they reference the same objects. so when you change value of an object in `peopleAtBlock1`, its reflected in `peopleAtBlock2` also.

In order to solve this you will have to create a deep copy of peopleAtBlock1. [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object) to do this is to use serialization. that is first you serialize the original data and then create a copy by de serializing.

there are better ways of doing this but a quick and easy way is to use JSON serialization, which can be done by following the below steps

First add dependency for [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) in your project as

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
```

Now move `Person` class outside the function, `Gson` doesn't work with local classes

Finally you can create a deep copy as

```
val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Person>>(){}.type
val json = Gson().toJson(peopleAtBlock1, type)
val peopleAtBlock2 = Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<Person>>(json, type)
```

Comment: it works now, thanks for your detailed answer. i wonder why kotlin/java doesn't provide deepclone for all object..

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Person.deepCopy(): Person = copy(friends = friends.map { it.deepCopy() })

val peopleAtBlock2 = peopleAtBlock1.map { it.deepCopy() }
```